# Как сделать чтобы переменная не была больше заданного числа

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

есть переменная

```
float timer = 15;
```

есть код который отбавляет -1 каждую секунду

```
timer -= Time.deltaTime;
    text.text = Mathf.Round(timer).ToString();
```

и есть код который прибавляет

```
if (other.CompareTag("Egg"))
    {
        timer += 5;
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
    }
```

Вопрос, как мне сделать чтоб переменная

```
timer
```

не была больше 15?

Answer (score 2):

я решил

```
if (timer >= 15)
{
    timer = 15;
}
```